# I cant get my location immediately after having given the permissions in google maps activity.What am i doing wrong?

Tags: android, google-maps, permissions

After asking the user for location permissions and accepts, it doesn't find the location, I have to go back and again inside the app in order to show my location. How can I achieve after giving location permissions to get my location instantly? 
This is my code

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;

    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 16f;

    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        //Gets the device's current location
        getLocationPermission();

        //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        //  openGpsWindow();
        //}


    }




    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        //map is ready

        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {

            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,

                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;

            }
            //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    private void getDeviceLocation() {

        // getting the device's current location

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);


        if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();



            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override

                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null){

                        //onComplete: found location

                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                        double latitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();

                        double longitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();


                        //Finding user's location
                        LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        moveCamera(myCoordinates, DEFAULT_ZOOM);




                        //Adding an icon marker to display the user's location and the info window from above
                        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
                        mMap.addMarker(marker.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_mini))).showInfoWindow();



                    }else{
                        //unable to get current location
                    }

                }

            });

        }

    }


    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom) {

        //moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: + latLng.latitude +  lng:  + latLng.longitude

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));


    }


    private void initMap() {

        //initializing map

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);


    }


    private void getLocationPermission() {

        //getting location permissions

        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,

                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),

                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),

                    COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;

                initMap();

            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,

                        permissions,

                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

            }

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,

                    permissions,

                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }

    }


    @Override

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //onRequestPermissionsResult: called

        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;


        switch (requestCode) {

            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {

                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

                            //onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed

                            return;

                        }

                    }

                    //onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted

                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;

                    //initialize the map

                    initMap();

                }

            }

        }

    }

    public void openGpsWindow() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EnableGpsWindow.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

2)And then If I disable gps while I am in mapsactivity i want to call openGpsWindow(which prompts user to go open the gps again.) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method that updates the UI with the location after the permission has been granted. For example:

```
private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                getLocationPermission();
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and then call that method after your initMap() method after the permission has been granted. 
If that does not work, you can look here https://github.com/PabiMoloi/Location/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/pmoloi/location/presentation/map/MapsActivity.java , it is a project i created that uses maps.

Comment: where exactly do I call this method??

Comment: You call it after the initMap() method call

Comment: I made few convertions and I made it, thanks to your code!! thanks so much! Maybe you could give me a help with my second query?